# Idiomatic Cypress way to assert that two elements that contains some text exist in the DOM

Tags: cypress

Using Cypress, what is the idiomatic way to assert that two elements exist in the DOM for a given selector (that also contain some text)?

Here's how I would do that in JavaScript:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("selector")).filter(node => node.textContent.includes("text")).length === 2
```

Is there an idiomatic way to do this in Cypress?

I've tried:

```js
cy.get('selector')
  .contains('text')
  .should('have.length', 2);
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> `cy.contains()` cannot be passed a length option because it will only ever return 1 element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use the below approach without the 'filter' option.

Example:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Same</td>
      <td>Same</td>
      <td>Different</td>
      <td>Same</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
// selects all table cells with text "Same"
cy.get('td:contains("Same")').should('have.length', 3)
// if the text does not have white spaces, no need to quote it
cy.get('td:contains(Same)').should('have.length', 3)
// you can find elements NOT having the given text
cy.get('td:not(:contains(Same))')
  .should('have.length', 1)
  .and('have.text', 'Different')
```

Read more at [here](https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/7.5.0/commands/querying.html#number-of-items)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter()` in combination with `contains()` like this. ([Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/filter#Filter-by-text))

```js
cy.get('selector')
  .filter(':contains("text")')
  .should('have.length', 2);
```